# Difference between synchronized(Singleton.class) and synchronized(obj)

Tags: java, synchronization, thread-safety, singleton

What is the difference between using the following two versions of Singleton Classes

**In the first I am using synchronized(Singleton.class)**

**In the Second I am using synchronized(Obj)**
//First Type
    public class Singleton {

```
private static Singleton obj = null;

Singleton() {
}

public static Singleton getInstance() {

    synchronized(Singleton.class){
        if (obj == null) {
        obj = new Singleton();
    }
}
    return obj;
}
```

}

//Second Type

```
public class Singleton {

private static Singleton obj = null;

Singleton() {
}

public static Singleton getInstance() {

    synchronized(obj){
        if (obj == null) {
        obj = new Singleton();
    }
}
    return obj;
}
}
```

Comment: synchronizing on null in second example does not make sense

Comment: Uhm, you do realize in your second version that at the first call you will synchronize on `null`? And why not initialize your singleton in a static initializer?

Comment: I am new to multithreading and so cant really understand what synchronized(<Object>) does? My naive understanding is tht whn we use synchronized(<Object>), we should enter the object/variable that we want to syncronize, bt i see in posts below tht we want to synchronize "obj" but we are passing syncRoot as a parameter or a generic object as a parameter. syncRoot is not even changing states or is not used in the block. Alternatively, even Singleton.class does not specify the object or variable to be synchronized, only the type, then how do we know what block/variables r to be synchronized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference is that `synchronized(obj)` is not going to work: the first time that you call it, `obj` is `null`, so you are going to see a `NullPointerException`.

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/LKLQ3Z)

`Singleton.class`, on the other hand, is never `null`, so you can use it for synchronization. However, there is an attack that can be executed by malicious code to make your `getInstance` method wait forever: all they need is to lock on your `Singleton.class`, and put an infinite wait there.

A common defense against this attack is to use a separate private static object for your lock, like this:

```
public class Singleton {

    private static Singleton obj = null;
    private static final Object syncRoot = new Object();

    Singleton() {
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        synchronized(syncRoot){
            if (obj == null) {
                obj = new Singleton();
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am new to multithreading and so cant really understand  what  synchronized(syncRoot) does? My naive understanding is that when we use  synchronized(<Object>), we should enter the object/variable that we want to synchronize, but i see that here we want to synchronize "obj" but we are passing syncRoot as a parameter. syncRoot is not even changing states or is not used in the block. Alternatively, even Singleton.class does not specify the object or variable to be synchronized, only the type, then how do we know what block/variables are/is to be synchronized.

Comment: @Sam `synchronized` construct takes an object - any object, and uses it as a lock. It is up to you to decide what actions you wish to lock. Java makes a guarantee that as long as the object is the same, at most one thread will be executing inside the `synchronized` block for that object. It does not matter what that object is, as long as it is non-null. I made the object private to ensure that other classes could not get to it legally.

Comment: I have a followup question, what does the idiom Classname.class return, does it return an object, I read somewhere that it is a static compile time call but could not comprehend what that meant?  In the aboe mentioned case (Singleton.class), as this is singleton, how can we create a default object using Singleton.class if att all that is what is happening. Thanks a lot for the explaining the Synchronization aspect as well.

Comment: @Sam The `Classname.class` syntax lets you obtain an object that represents the class `Classname`. The "real" purpose of the `Class` object is to let you discover at runtime what are the methods and fields of a specific class. As an idiom, `Classname.class` is sometimes used in `synchronize` blocks to guard access to per-class objects, because Java guarantees that there's only one class object for each class loaded into JVM.

Comment: Could you help me out on this one. Im startled, its a tricky question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22846484/how-woud-you-design-a-collabritive-shareable-text-editor-key-points-are-given

Answer (score 1):

The second version attempts to synchronize on `null`, which will fail. The `synchronized` keyword attempts to acquire the lock on the `Object` referred to by `obj`, and since it is initially `null`, you will get a `NulPointerException`.

Answer (score 1):

They are effectively the same, and also a bad implementation as obj IS NULL (in your example) and the code single threads every call to it.  It should use double-check-lock...

second one should be:

```
public class Singleton {
   private static object syncRoot = new object();
   private static Singleton obj = null

   Singleton() {
   }

   public static Singleton getInstance() {

      if ( obj == null ){
        //ONLY SINGLE THREAD IF obj == null
        synchronized(syncRoot){
          if ( obj == null ){
             obj = new Singleton();            
          }
        }
      }
      return obj;
   }
}
```

Comment: [The "Double-Checked Locking is Broken" Declaration](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html)

Answer (score 0):

when you use synchronized(Singleton.class) the synchronization gets applied only until the first time an instance is created, and its used when we have a scenario where their is possibility of  multiple thread running thru our code. Your if loop will take care of not creating another instance when already one is available, by using this way of synchronization we reduce a lot of over head since we know synchronized classes add over head in terms of time/wait.