# How would you design a Collabritive/ Shareable Text Editor: Key points are given below

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, oop, design-patterns

Read/Write operations by multiple users.
A user may be able to make the editor read only i.e only the creator of the session writes.
You should be able to share the link of the current session to add more users to work on simultaneously.
It should be concurrent(synchronization) and avoid editing conflicts. Suggest approach to do this.
Please focus on a correct and scalable functionality.
Should have auto save
Editor should maintain changes/edits on each save.
Support rollback to any change.
Must have share/like functionality for social media.

I was able to come with the following, need help identifying classes to build a class diagram for this:

It will be a client server implementation.

For website, client can be written in HTML5 and Javascript. We can use additional javascript frameworks for specific requirements(eg. angularjs).

For sending request two methods are available:
1. Request/Response
-- Sending request every second
2. Long pooling 
-- Make a never ending http request to server and communicate through it. This method will be way faster that earlier one because multiple http request will not be made.

Its the work of client to send the changes to server on fixed interval (1 second). 
Its the work of client to understand the changes done by other users and display the same to current user.

Server will be expose an API which will be used to
-- Get current document
-- SendUpdate request whose response will contain modification done by other users on same document. We will try and capture the delta and represent the changes on the client side.

Server Stack has to be very fast(.node.js or golang will be suitable for such requirement) because of its very short response time.
Data should be stored in memory, we can use Redis to store data. We can on intervals or on explicit save requests, save data on the file system or non in memory databases also.

Every request will contain set of changes made by client.
These changes will be saved in Redis along with timestamp. 
We wont be store whole file in database, we will just store historic changes. As redis is based on memory, it will take very little resource to compute final document from set of stored changes.

For every document there will be unique id associated with it. Unique id should be long enough.
You can create a url for notepads like example.com/notepad/{unique-id}
This will load the client and then load the document related to that unique id.

For every request this unique id will be send to identify which document is being edited by user.
Save
As every change is being sent to database, it will be auto saved.

Revert
You can keep historic data in AngularJs. If you want persistence between sessions, store data to file system.
You can also retrieve historic information from server using API. Which can be undone.

Facebook Share
We can also use FB graph api to post link in user;s timeline or Facebook exposes a sharer.php url, which can be used to share Post / Share a link in user's timeline.

Scalability
We can use cloud based scalable solutions like Mmazon AWS EC2 instances to implement this solution. We can keep webserver behind a load balancer.
We have to keep redis as separate (large) ec2 instance. There can be multiple webserver behind load balanacer. 
All of them will be communicating with Redis instance.
We can keep static data like css and js in CDN (AWS CloudFront behind S3)

Comment: It seems to me that you need a version control system. This is non-trivial to implement it "in urgency".Check out what you can find about document management systems and see what you can use

Comment: This question is far beyond the "extremely tricky" mark: getting it right has been enough for an internet start-up (namely,  Writely, aka Upstartle) to be purchased by Google.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight And this has been asked as a final assignment for an interview. I need to submit in a day, I know the approach but the classes and methods to represent in a class diagram are little difficult. Any high level class examples, anyone?

Comment: I will post whatever I could write on this in some time, hope someone can help me from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be a client server implementation.
Where server will be expose an API which will be used to
-- Get current document
-- SendUpdate request whose response will contain modification done by other users on same document

Its the work of client to send the changes to server on fixed interval (say 1 second). 
Its the work of client to understand the changes done by other users and display the same to current user.

For website, client can be written in HTML5 and Javascript. You can use AngularJs as javascript framework for the same.
For sending request two methods are available:
1. Synchronization
-- Sending request every second
2. Long pooling 
-- Make a never ending http request to server and communicate through it. This method will be way faster that earlier one because multiple http request will not be made.

Server Stack has to be very fast. node.js or golang will be suitable for such requirement, because of its very short response time.
Data should be stored in memory, you can use Redis to store data.

Every request will contain set of changes made by client.
These changes will be saved in Redis along with timestamp. 
You wont store whole file in database, you should just store historic changes. As redis is based on memory, it will take very little resource to compute final document from set of stored changes.

Comment: and what are best friends for :)